# Refactor file copy in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, resharper, macros

Does Visual Studio / Resharper support this? By refactor copy I mean to be able to enter new class name in some dialog, and to have the tool do all the refactoring (renaming) for you. No Copy of ... file names, and no error upon having two classes with same name in the project.

Netbeans does this out-of-the-box :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper (4.5) does that. You goto `Refactor -> Copy type` and enter a new name (& namespace). It created the new type in a new file with a corresponding name.

As far as I can see VS2008 does not support this. But my ReSharper hides a lot of VS-stuff - so maybe someone without ReSharper can confirm this?

Comment: ReSharper 4.0 also supports it ... And I need a new pair of glasses :D

Thx!

Comment: the key combo Ctrl+R, O is the default short cut to that operation.